# ActionScript 3 MouseEvent run once

Tags: actionscript-3

What I want to do is to run once my over listener function. The problem is that once I do a mouse over into my movie clip "button",  it  enters a new loop again and again. How can I make it run **only** once, when the tween event is completed ?

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

function Over (e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace('Over');
var myTweenUp:Tween = new Tween(button, "y", Back.easeOut, 200, 180, 2, true);
}

function Out (e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace('Out');
var myTweenDown:Tween = new Tween(button, "y", Back.easeOut, 180, 200, 2, true);
}
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Out);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the above code.

I think you are adding the code as a Frame Script i.e on the frame of the timeline in the IDE.

If that is the case, simply add `stop();` before the above code snippet.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

stop();

// ... rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution from **@loxxy** should do the trick.  **Try that solution first.**

If not, then try removing the listener once the event fires.  You can re-add it later, too.

E.g.:

```
function Over (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);
    [...]
}

function Out (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want run those two MouseEvent, you can add removeEventListener to make it.

```
function Over (e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace('Over');
var myTweenUp:Tween = new Tween(button, "y", Back.easeOut, 200, 180, 2, true);
button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);
}

function Out (e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace('Out');
var myTweenDown:Tween = new Tween(button, "y", Back.easeOut, 180, 200, 2, true);
button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Out);
}

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Out);
```

If you want to make a loop that when hover mouse on the button running Over and get out running Out and one by one, you can try the coding below:

```
function Over (e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace('Over');
var myTweenUp:Tween = new Tween(button, "y", Back.easeOut, 200, 180, 2, true);
button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Out);
}

function Out (e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace('Out');
var myTweenDown:Tween = new Tween(button, "y", Back.easeOut, 180, 200, 2, true);
button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Out);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);
}

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Over);
```